# I get error : only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: numpy, math

[here my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdr6T.png)

I get an error like that, how to fix my code?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-68d70726d35a> in <module>
----> 1 Y2 = f(x,y)
      2 Err = abs (Y2-y)

<ipython-input-1-73d0ce0a26c4> in f(x, y)
      3 from matplotlib.pyplot import*
      4 def f(x,y) :
----> 5     return np.exp(-2*x)((sqrt(3)/6)*sin(2*sqrt(3)*x)+(1/2)*cos(2*sqrt(3)*x))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use math library sin and cos since you are using sin and cos from math library which expect scaler, but in code screenshot added it look fine and also run, replace your f with this, and also please dont upload screenshots.

```
import numpy as np
def f(x, y):
    return np.exp(-2*x)*((np.sqrt(3)/6)*np.sin(2*np.sqrt(3)*x)+(1/2)*np.cos(2*np.sqrt(3)*x))
```